# how do i access a field of a contoller variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

in my controller i have a variable `Custom_obj_c c` with a getter method that is called in the constructor. In my visualforce, how do i access the fields of c?

sorry, i've got a brain freeze right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Custom_Obj__c c` must be public with a getter and setter, like this:

```
public Custom_Obj__c c { get; set; }
```

It can then be accessed through the binding `c`:

```
{!c.Field__c}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Error: Unknown property 'BytecodeApexObject.myField__c'

Comment: We're probably going to need to see some source code, then. Can you show us your controller and page?

Comment: i got it to work.. is there a way to customize the  getter?

Comment: You can use a getter body, like: `public custom_obj__c c { get { if(c==null) c = new custom_obj__c(); return c; } set; }`

Comment: that works, thanks! can you explain why i need to write the getters and setters like that? usually i define the object `public obj__c c;` and then have getter and a setter later in the code as "seperate methods

Comment: Both methods work nearly identically, especially from a Visualforce perspective. There are differences when using getters/setters in Apex Code. Consider: `Integer x { get { x = x == null ? 0 : x + 1; return x; } set; }`. You can now do this: `while( x < 100 ) { /* do something, x counts itself! */ }`, while using `getX() { x = x == null ? 0 : x+1; return x; }` doesn't allow the prior loop to work the same way, has to be written as `while(getX() < 100) { ...`. Sometimes you want the logic in the variable, sometimes not.